# How to determine if the tcsh script is being sourced within the script [tcsh, not bash]

Tags: shell, tcsh

How can I determine if the current `tcsh` script is being sourced (within the script)?

What I tried:

```
if (!($0 == "-tcsh")) then
    echo "Script should be sourced."
    exit 1
endif
```

If I'll try without source it will print `Script should be sourced.` (As expected).

But If I'll try with source, it will fail with the following error: `if: Malformed file inquiry.`.

How can I fix this problem? Is there a better way to check it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a nasty trick you can play here by looking at `$_`.

> **`$_`** Substitutes the command line of the last command executed.

If you place this in the first line of your script, and the outcome is not an empty string (i.e. a command has been executed before), then the script has been sourced.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
set sourced = ($_)
if ("$sourced" == "") then
   echo "Script should be sourced."
   exit 1
endif
```

Information picked from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/determining-path-to-sourced-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

While there might be other ways to do that, a simple enhancement to your own method works fine. Just enclose the $0 within double quotes. 
i.e change the line

```
if (!($0 == "-tcsh")) then
```

to

```
if (!("$0" == "-tcsh")) then
```

Answer (score 0):

[kvantour's anwser](/a/51932311) is wrong.  In tcsh the value of `$_` will not be set correctly unless the script is sourced from a command line/terminal.  There is a guy at Intel that works on their icc compiler that must think the same way, which is where my issue is.

Simple example to prove the point:

#### `script.csh`:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "Got: " $_
```

**In a terminal:**

Run `source script.csh`; you will get the output of "Got: source script.csh"

Run `script.csh`; you will get the output of "Got: "

Run `ssh $HOST 'source script.csh'`; you will get the output of "**Got:** "

So even though you sourced the script the `$_` value is not set.  This happens when you have a headless terminal.  So if I put `source scripts.csh` inside of my `.cshrc`, `$_` will not be set, which causes issues.  So do not implement the solution here.

If I find the **right** answer I will update this post.

Comment: And what shell is `ssh $HOST` invoking on the far end?  A better demonstration (that removes lots of unknowns) is `csh -c 'source script.csh'`, which shows the same result.  (I don't use csh myself, but I'd guess that `$_` is set only for interactive commands, and that's what you're demonstrating here)